# browse to remote Glassfish admin page?

Tags: server, application-development, webserver, aws, glassfish

On `AWS` it's easy enough to start glassfish:

```
ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu:~$ asadmin start-domain
Waiting for domain1 to start .....
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: /home/ubuntu/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1
Log File: /home/ubuntu/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.
ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu:~$ lynx localhost:4848 -dump
GlassFish Server Administration Console

   Status indicator image. Status: The Admin Console is already installed,
   but not yet loaded.

   If the browser does not refresh the page automatically please reload
   the page.
ubuntu:~$
```

but how do you view the GUI admin console from a web browser?  While I can `ssh` from this IP address, can't seem to browse to the Glassfish admin page.  (Or even a welcome page.)

Can you not access Glassfish on a remote server?

Answer (score 1):

If you can SSH to that server, just forward the Glassfish port your system. Say:

```
ssh -R localhost:4848:localhost:8080 aws-ip
```

And then open `http://localhost:8080` in your local system's browser.

Comment: on my local system run that command? the `aws-ip` is the **external** ip address for the aws server?